# Set labels of multiple wxTextCtrls to empty values using foreach

Tags: c++, wxwidgets, deque, mem-fun

I've been trying to set multiple labels of wxTextCtrl to empty values using for_each like this:

```
std::deque<wxTextCtrl*> dqImg;

for_each (dqImg.begin(),dqImg.end(),bind1st(mem_fun(&wxTextCtrl::SetLabel),""));
```

the problem is it gives me this error:

```
Error 1 error C2535: 'void std::binder1st<_Fn2>::operator ()(const wxString &) const' : member function already defined or declared d:\...\visualstudio2012\vc\include\xfunctional  286
```

Could you please explain me what am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: I don't think this answers your question but the correct method for setting `wxTextCtrl` contents is `SetValue()`, not `SetLabel()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really understand the error message (which version of the compiler do you use?) but you should use `bind2nd`, not `bind1st`, because the first parameter of the functor returned by `mem_fun()` is `wxTextCtrl*`.

Comment: Thanks, it worked with bind2nd. I also changed the argument "" - I made a const wxString str = "" which I put there.